# Ensemble learning

Tags: machine-learning, ensemble-modeling, bayesian

I am currently working to build a mathematical model to predict the stock market. I learned that the best way to do such thing is no longer to make one big best model, but rather to gather several models together where it follows best results. This technique is called [ensemble learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning).

What is the best `ensemble learning` method? Bayes Optimal classifier?

Do I have to take an ensemble learning that

- trains several different models using training data, and picks the one that works best with the test data?
- runs multiple models at once on the data, and combines the results together?
- is an alternative technique where each ensemble boost attibutes that address data mis-classified by the previous model?
- ...?

**P.S.** Please tell me if the question is unclear.

Comment: Assume I have some interesting algorithms that allow me the minimize risk to lost money on the stock market. I would like that those algorithm could work together in such a way it could improve the global model. I know I could use a strategy like using ensemble learning. However, I just don't know which one is the most efficient for that kind of model. My question is : What ensemble learning is suggested for that kind of project? Bayes Optimal classifier? Bucket of models? Stacking? Bootstrap aggregating?

Comment: Agree with Bashar, the question is too broad. Bashar's answer give a great overview of the ensemble. However do take note that there is no best technique/model that fits for all data. sure there is some models that are more suited than others based on a glance at the type of data you have. But the only way you're getting the best model available is to try out the different models and see which gives you the best score.

Comment: Too broad question , try to be more specific . My answer is also too broad just to give you an idea

Answer (score 2):

Ensemble learning is categorized into 4 different classes: bagging, boosting, stacking, hierarchy classification and sometimes they consider grading as another category. Each one of these categories has many different types. For example, in boosting you have [Adaboost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost), [Gboost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting) and [many others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning#Common_types_of_ensembles).

It is very important to understand the differences between these categories and why each one is important. Let me give you a brief idea. Bagging is very important to be used when you have one learning algorithm that is unstable , bagging can reduce the variance error. Boosting is very important when you have variations within classes, boosting can be used to generate different learners that focus on different samples ( specifically, difficult samples), stacking based classifier is a selector algorithm used to reduce bias error.

It is highly recommended to read a survey about ensemble learning to get a better idea which method to use. Remember to read also about cross validation that can be used to test and validate selection. Read also about imbalance data base and how over sampling, under sampling and SMOTE algorithm can be used to deal with these problems

Comment: I've never heard of grading. Do you have a resource which introduces it?

Comment: Grading is one of the ensemble classification techniques. The classifier consists of two layers of base classifiers. while the first layer performs predictions, the second layer performs corrections.  https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-44816-0_12

Comment: Thank you :-) So grading in deep learning is essentially only making the classifier deeper.

Answer (score -1):

> Do I have to take an ensemble learning that

You don't have to do anything. As so often with machine learning questions, there is no obvious answer what will work better / best. Most of the time, you just have to try it.

For a general overview over ensembling techniques, see my blog post: https://martin-thoma.com/ensembles/

Keywords to look for are: Bagging, boosting, stacking